# How to close pandas.scatter_matrix() figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm hitting `MemoryError: In RendererAgg: Out of memory` when I plot several `pandas.scatter_matrix()` figures.

Normally I use:

`plt.close(fig)`

to close `matplotlib` figures, so that I release the memory used, but `pandas.scatter_matrix()` does not return a `matplotlib` figure, rather it returns the axes object. For example:

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
ax = pd.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)`

How do I close this figure?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of investigation, I realized that I could just use:

`plt.close()`

with no argument to close the current figure, or:

`plt.close('all')`

to close all of the opened figures.